# Program calculating Square Root

Tags: c#

I am a student and unfortunately, online learning is really not learning, more like following a step by step with explanation of "why", so I am struggling to figure this out and any help with explanation would be amazing!
I am trying to write a program that calculates the square root of a number without using Math.Sqrt. What I have so far calculates whole numbers and gives a result of a whole number or decimal. But where I'm having trouble is if the user enters a negative number, then the program breaks. The second part I need help is to add code prompting the user to enter a number if they enter a word. This is what I have so far:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

//Calculate the square root of decimals and whole numbers

namespace Sqaure_Root
{
    
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void okClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            double number = Convert.ToDouble(userInput.Text);
            double root = 1, temp = 0;
 
            //Calculate square root
           
            while (root != temp)
            {
                temp = root;
                root = (number / root + root) / 2;
            }
            
            if (number < 0)
            {
                resultBx.Text = ("Please enter a positive number");
                number = Convert.ToDouble(userInput.Text);
            }

            else
            {
                resultBx.Text = ("Please enter a number");
            }
            
            resultBx.Text = root.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should do the check for negatives _before_ the calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's extract a *method*: we want user to enter a valid positive *double* value:

```
  private bool TryReadDouble(out double result) {
    if (!double.TryParse(userInput.Text, out result)) {
      resultBx.Text = "Sorry, not a number. Please, enter a non-negative value.";   

      return false;
    }
    else if (result < 0) { 
      resultBx.Text = "Please, enter a non-negative value.";   

      return false;
    } 
    else if (double.IsNaN(result)) { // <- from now on let's be a bit paranoic
      resultBx.Text = "Please, enter a valid non-negative value.";   

      return false;
    }
    else if (double.IsInfinity(result)) {
      resultBx.Text = "Please, enter a finite non-negative value.";   

      return false;
    }

    // result is finite non-negative value
    return true;         
  }
```

Now you can use this method in the main routine:

```
  private void okClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (!TryReadDouble(out var number))
      return; 

    // number is a non-negative double value; no further check required 
    // time to compute the square root:

    double root = 1;

    // Math.Abs(temp - root) > ... - we should compare double with some tolerance 
    for (double temp = 0; Math.Abs(temp - root) > 1e-8; ) {
      temp = root;
      root = (number / root + root) / 2;
    }
   
    resultBx.Text = root.ToString();                    
  }
```